# Can't pass dictionary in Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

So I was trying something new and I decided to try Django... And I was building a self motivated project of a hotel eCommerce site.. I was playing around with different template tags and I found moyself in a bit of a pickle... :/ Below is the attached code, if you have time to check it... Thank You... Also I have another question: Does include tag automatically inherits the contexts from the index html or should I have to pass the context from the index page with a 'with' keyword? Although I tried both "with" and without "with" with no luck. Thanks again, I am stuck in this for quite some time now...

## My views.py

```
def home_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    ob1 = Room.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'Rooms': ob1})
```

## My included html snippet:

```
{% if not Rooms %}
     <script type="text/javascript">console.log("No!!")</script>
{% endif %}
{% if Rooms %}
   {% for room in Rooms %}
    <h1>{{ room.Room_Types }}</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">console.log("Yes!!")</script>
   {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Sadly, The console log was always no!!! ;(

Comment: BTW the {% for room in rooms %} is actually  {% for room in Rooms %} that was not the mistake... I mistyped in the question

Comment: You can edit your questions

Comment: What is the error message you are getting, that really helps to narrow down the problem? Also have you tried https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Please `print` your `ob1` in your view and show what it prints

Comment: @Daniel there was no error message, so I had to print out in the console... The Rooms context is null to begin with... and I don't know how to counteract that... Would it help if I post the index.html?

Comment: @GProst should I provide the shell output in the question?

Comment: I don't see what the error or unexpected behavior is so it is hard to give an answer to your question. What is it that you are expecting to happen and what is happening?

Comment: I want to pass the Rooms Dictionary and display it to the html... That was my goal... and also I wanted to know  is include tag in django passes the context in the index html to the included html? Thanks...

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#include, they say that the included template gets rendered with the context of the parent template. So yes, you should have access to `Rooms` in your included snippet.